# In JSP/Java how can I replace getter/setter by s.th. more generic?

Tags: java, setter, getter

I am getting tired by adding tons of getters/setters all the time in my beans.
Is there a simple way to use annotations to get rid of this stupid work?
or any other way? The 2nd example is the short version, which I would like to run, since there is no need to encapsulte my members (though in another context it might be neccessary).
In my real world I have to access about 15 classes with about 10 data members in each class which would produce 300 useless setters/getters.

Example TestPerson.java (works):

```
public class TestPerson {
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public TestPerson() {
    firstName = "Hugo";
  }
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

Example TestPerson.java (does NOT work):

```
public class TestPerson {
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public TestPerson() {
    firstName = "Hugo";
  }
}
```

Example test.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="testperson" class="test.TestPerson" scope="request" />
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Results</h2>${testperson.firstName}<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have answered your own question. you don't need to encapsulate, so go ahead expose public fields. just don't let the moral police notice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) solves this (and much more), and it has support for both [Eclipse](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/42946/1954) and [Netbeans](http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/lombok_meets_netbeans_and_java).

Comment: Lombok seems to be what I have searched for

Answer (score 9):

Just have your IDE to autogenerate them. In Eclipse for example, define some properties, rightclick source, choose *Source* and then *Generate Getters and Setters*.

[image]

Comment: this is from eclispe, he is asking particuarly for netbeans

Comment: @Damodar: Where do you read this? The OP's question history confirms that he's using Eclipse. Or are you confusing "beans" with "Netbeans"?

Comment: a good idea, too, but an even better solution is to get rid of getter/setter totally in my sources

Comment: No problem. This is however going to hit you sooner or later :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the Groovy scripting language? It is based on Java and generates Java Bytecode.

See this link: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans the getters and the setters are implicit.

Answer (score 0):

There's also scala as well:

```
class foo {
   @BeanProperty
   var s1 : String,
   @BeanProperty
   var i1 : int
}
```

You could use the scala compiler to generate java byte code, which would create this class, along with the appropriate private fields, and getter and setter methods.

However, assuming you want to stick with plain java, i doubt java will see first class property support any time soon.  Your best bet is some kind of code generation.  It would be possible to generate these via annotations and annotation handlers, though this might give eclipse fits.  EDIT:  This is what Lombok (as mentioned above) appears to be doing.  It's generating source code for you at  compile time based on the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Try [write-it-once](https://code.google.com/p/write-it-once/). Template based code generator. You write custom template using [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates), and generate file depending on java reflections. It's the simplest way to generate any file. You can make getters/settest/toString by generating AspectJ or java files, SQL based on JPA annotations, inserts / updates based on enums and so on.